# Having much trouble with 'preallocating cell arrays' in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I have recently switched from programming heavily in MATLAB to programming in Python. Hence I am having some issues running the Python code that I have written. I am using numPy and SciPy to integrate an arbitrary set of ordinary differential equations, with method **vode**. I have generalized the system of ODEs for any number 'N' of them, but run into problems with preallocating and using arrays.

It is especially frustrating for me because I have TWO versions of fully functional MATLAB code, but need to convert it to Python for optimized results. And I am having trouble. Especially with the following lines:

```
S = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')
KS = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')
PS = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')
Splot = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')
KSplot = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')
PSplot = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')
```

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate

N = 10
K00 = np.logspace(0,3,101,10)
len1 = len(K00)
epsilon = 0.01
y0 = [0]*(3*N/2+3)
u1 = 0
u2 = 0
u3 = 0
Kplot = np.zeros((len1,1))
Pplot = np.zeros((len1,1))
S = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')
KS = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')
PS = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')
Splot = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')
KSplot = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')
PSplot = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')

for alpha in range(0,(N/2+1)):
    Splot[alpha] = np.zeros((len1,1))
for beta in range((N/2)+1,N+1):
    KSplot[beta-N/2-1] = np.zeros((len1,1))
for gamma in range(N+1,3*N/2+1):
    PSplot[gamma-N] = np.zeros((len1,1))

for series in range(0,len1):
    K0 = K00[series]
    Q = 10
    r1 = 0.0001
    r2 = 0.001
    a = 0.001
    d = 0.001
    k = 0.999
    S10 = 1e5
    P0 = 1

    def f(y, t):
        for alpha in range(0,(N/2+1)):
            S[alpha] = y[alpha]
        for beta in range((N/2)+1,N+1):
            KS[beta-N/2-1] = y[beta]
        for gamma in range(N+1,3*N/2+1):
            PS[gamma-N] = y[gamma]
        K = y[3*N/2+1]
        P = y[3*N/2+2]

        ydot = np.zeros((3*N/2+3,1))
        B = range((N/2)+1,N+1)
        G = range(N+1,3*N/2+1)
        runsumPS = 0
        runsum1 = 0
        runsumKS = 0 
        runsum2 = 0

        for m in range(0,N/2):
            runsumPS = runsumPS + PS[m+1]
            runsum1 = runsum1 + S[m+1]
            runsumKS = runsumKS + KS[m]
            runsum2 = runsum2 + S[m]    
            ydot[B[m]] = a*K*S[m]-(d+k+r1)*KS[m]

        for i in range(0,N/2-1):
            ydot[G[i]] = a*P*S[i+1]-(d+k+r1)*PS[i+1]

        for p in range(1,N/2):
            ydot[p] = -S[p]*(r1+a*K+a*P)+k*KS[p-1]+ \
                      d*(PS[p]+KS[p])

        ydot[0] = Q-(r1+a*K)*S[0]+d*KS[0]+k*runsumPS
        ydot[N/2] = k*KS[N/2-1]-(r2+a*P)*S[N/2]+ \
                    d*PS[N/2]
        ydot[G[N/2-1]] = a*P*S[N/2]-(d+k+r2)*PS[N/2]
        ydot[3*N/2+1] = (d+k+r1)*runsumKS-a*K*runsum2
        ydot[3*N/2+2] = (d+k+r1)*(runsumPS-PS[N/2])- \
                        a*P*runsum1+(d+k+r2)*PS[N/2]

        for j in range(0,3*N/2+3):
            return ydot[j] 

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        r = integrate.ode(f).set_integrator('vode', method='bdf')  
        t_start = 0.0
        t_final = 1e10
        delta_t = t_final/(len1-1)
        num_steps = np.floor((t_final - t_start)/delta_t) + 1

        y0[0] = S10
        for i in range(1,3*N/2+1):
            y0[i] = 0
        y0[3*N/2+1] = K0
        y0[3*N/2+2] = P0
        r.set_initial_value(y0, t_start)

        t = np.zeros((num_steps, 1))
        soln = np.array(np.zeros((num_steps, 1))*(3*N/2+3))
        t[0] = t_start
        for i in range(0,3*N/2+3):
            soln[i] = y0[i]

        k = 1
        while r.successful() and k < num_steps:
            r.integrate(r.t + delta_t)

            t[k] = r.t
            for jj in range(0,3*N/2+3):
                soln[k] = r.y[jj]
            k += 1
```

The error message is below:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\dis_YO_boi\Documents\Programming\Python\ArrayMod.py in <module>()
     21 
     22 for alpha in range(0,(N/2+1)):
---> 23     Splot[alpha] = np.zeros((len1,1))
     24 for beta in range((N/2)+1,N+1):
     25     KSplot[beta-N/2-1] = np.zeros((len1,1))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (101,1) into shape (1)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `Splot` is a `N/2 + 1 x 1` 2D matrix, yet you are trying to squeeze 101 elements into a single element in this matrix.  That doesn't work.  Have you considered using **lists** instead?  These better reflect cell array behaviour in Python.  http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before trying to fully understand your code, let me observe that constructs like:

```
S = np.array(np.zeros((N/2+1,1)), dtype = 'object')
```

are not good `numpy`.

You are probably imitating the MATLAB cell arrays.  Python had 'cells' long before MATLAB.  Python lists can hold are diverse set of values, strings, numbers, other lists, arrays, etc.

`numpy` arrays with `dtype=object` are just glorified lists.  They may be convenient if you want 2d collections, but as with MATLAB you can't do math across elements of such arrays.  At best you can iterate over them, just as you would with lists.

It's possible that your error has nothing to do with that, but I'll have to dig a bit to be sure.

---

```
Splot=np.array(np.zeros((4,1)),dtype=object)
```

produces a `(4,1)` array, with dtype=object.  `np.array` tries to create as high a dimensional array as it can from the inputs.

From 
    for alpha in range(0,(N/2+1)):
        Splot[alpha] = np.zeros((len1,1))

it looks like you wanted to preallocate an an array with these `N/2+1` slots, and fill each with a 2d array.  It's a little tricky with `dtype=object`.

```
Splot = [np.zeros((len1,1)) for alpha in range(M)]
```

would produce a list with M arrays, each of the same length.

e.g.

```
In [67]: Splot=[np.zeros((4,1)) for alpha in range(3)]

In [68]: Splot
Out[68]: 
[array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]]),
 array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]]),
 array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]])]
```

Note that I wrap this list of 2d arrays in an array, I get a 3d array:

```
In [69]: np.array(Splot)
Out[69]: 
array([[[ 0.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.]],

       [[ 0.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.]],

       [[ 0.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.]]])

In [70]: _.shape
Out[70]: (3, 4, 1)
```

It is possible to make an array of arrays with this strategy.

Make an object array of the right size (`np.empty` will fill it with `None`).

```
In [72]: Splot
Out[72]: array([0, 0, 0], dtype=object)
```

Then iterate to replace each `0` with a new object.

```
In [73]: for i in range(3):
   ....:     Splot[i] = np.zeros((4,1))
   ....:     

In [74]: Splot
Out[74]: 
array([array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]]),
       array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]]),
       array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input